# Jsoup returned string " " is not returning true on equals(" ")

Tags: java, jsoup, equals

Just playing around and pulling some data off a site to manipulate when I come across this:

```
String request = "http://foo";
String data = "bar";

Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(request).data(data).method(Method.POST).execute();
Document doc = res.parse();
Elements all = doc.select("td");

for(Element elem : all){
    String test = elem.text();
    if(test.equals(" ")){
       //redefine  test to 0 and print it
    }
    else{
       //print it
}
```

The site in question is coded as so:

```
<td align="center">Henry</td>
<td>23</td>
<td align="center">Savannah</td>
<td>15</td></tr>
...
<td align="center"> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="center">Jane</td>
<td>15</td></tr>
```

In my for loop, `test` is never redefined.

I've debugged in Eclipse and `String test` is showing as so:

[image: eclipse debug]

---

Edit

Debugging test chartAt(0):

[image: chartat0]

---

`org.jsoup.nodes.Element.text()` says "Returns unencoded text or empty string if none".  I'm assuming the unencoded part has something to do with this, but I can't figure it out.

I ran a test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = " ";
    if (str.equals(" ")){
        System.out.println("True");
    }
}
```

and it returns true.

What gives?

Comment: Try checking exactly what `test.charAt(0)` is in the debugger.

Comment: That's weird. Is there any other running thread that might be changing `test`?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun No other threads. `test` is only defined inside the for loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet Check my edit.  It appears there is a space there.

Comment: @patterned: No, it just shows that it's whitespace. You want to see the Unicode character number. Your debugger screenshot doesn't really show the return value of `test.charAt(0)` at all as far as I can see.

Comment: Do a `System.out.println((int)test.charAt(0))` and compare it with `System.out.println((int)" ".charAt(0))`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ah... `test.chartAt(0)` == 160. `" ".chartAt(0)` == 32

Comment: It's a non-break space.  Don't understand why they put it there (governmental website).  How can I test for this unicode character?  Edit:  well I guess I can do `test.charAt(0) == 160`

Comment: Yeah check for either 160 or 32.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks.  Write an answer up and I'll accept it, if you care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you control the HTML being sent in the body of the response or if that is what you see in a browser's source page or elsewhere

```
<td> </td>
```

But it's possible the actual content is

```
<td>&nbsp</td> // or &#160
```

where `&nbsp` is the HTML entity for the [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

In java, you can represent it as

```
char nbsp = 160;
```

So you could just check for both `char` values, the one for space and the one for non-breaking space.

Note that there might be other codepoints that are represented as white space. You need to know what you're looking for.